# Flutter how to get value span class with nth-child(1) from web-scraper

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, css-selectors

i want to get value span class with nth-child(1)
Above image , CSS Selector is like this.

web snippet code :

```
div#__layout div:nth-child(1) > div > div.bonusHistoryDistTable__currencySymbol.cell.cell--leftAlignedColumn > div.cell__contentWrapper > span
```

Flutter snippet code :

```
List<String> currency_01 = [];

void _fetchTop4() async { final response = await http .get(Uri.parse("https://dovewallet.kr/ko/bonus-distribution-history"));                                                                                                                                                                 dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

debugPrint('11111');

final elements = document.querySelector(
    'div#__layout div:nth-child(1) > div > div.bonusHistoryDistTable__currencySymbol.cell.cell--leftAlignedColumn > div.cell__contentWrapper > span');

debugPrint('22222');

debugPrint('elements_fetchTop4:==========================>>> $elements');

setState(() {
   /*
   currency_01 = elements
      .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHtml).toList();*/
   debugPrint('currency_01:==========================>>> $currency_01');
});
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? if help you upvote to question and answer . thanks [How to collect data from website or (web scraping) via flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026492/how-to-collect-data-from-website-or-web-scraping-via-flutter)