# How to collect data from website or (web scraping) via flutter?

Tags: flutter, web-scraping, flutter-dependencies

I need to web scraping and collect data from the website https://ipcost.com and use that collected data (in this case, my IP details) in my Flutter app.

My question is how to get this information and display it in the UI.

[image: screenshot from https://ipcost.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the web_scraper package and it solved the problem.

**Step 1 :** add  web_scraper to dependencies .

**Step 2 :** Checking the website and getting the pattern of placing the desired information on the website. in my case
for "Titles" , pattern is :

```
'div.e > small'
```

for "Subtitle" , pattern is :

```
'div.e > strong'
```

**Step 3 :** I created an object of the Webscraper class and defined it by setting the value of the website URL.

**Step 4-1 :**
In my case , I don't need urlPath and set it empty .

```
  final String urlPath = '';
```

**Step 4-2 :**  In my case , Attributes always null and I don't need them.

```
  final List<String> attributeList = [''];
```

**Step 5 :** I define one method and call them in initState ,  for get values from website .

```
  void fetchData() async {
    if (await webScraper.loadWebPage(urlPath)) {
      setState(() {
        webScrapeResultTitle =
            webScraper.getElement(innerAddressTitle, attributeList);
        webScrapeResultDescription =
            webScraper.getElement(innerAddressDescription, attributeList);


        ///TODO:  By review this prints  , I detect structure of recievied data .


        // print("webScrapeResultTitle::::${webScrapeResultTitle!.toList()}");
        // print(
        //     "webScrapeResultDescription::::${webScrapeResultDescription!.toList()}");
      });
    }
  }
```

**Step 6 :** set build method like below for show results .

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: webScrapeResultTitle == null || webScrapeResultDescription == null
          ? Center(
        child: LoadingWidget(),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: webScrapeResultDescription!.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return IpInfoItem(
                titleResult: webScrapeResultTitle![index][titleResultKey],
                descriptionResult: webScrapeResultDescription![index]
                [descriptionResultKey]);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: result of web scraping in flutter on emulator]

****See my full code from here****

Gist full Snippets: [Gist.Github.com](https://gist.github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/ed69de5e7f19dfb9ae87bd79c8012008)

Repository : [Github.com](https://github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/Flutter_Web_Scraper)